# Python Mock Object Iterator Not Able To Iterate Multiple Times

Tags: python, unit-testing, iterator, mocking

I am using the mock iterator functionality to return an iterator for unit tests. In the code that I am testing, the I loop through the object multiple times, but it doesn't seem to be working and only works the first time.

```
self.mock_scene.bpyscene.objects.__iter__ = mock.Mock(return_value=iter([mock_lamp_object, mock_lamp_object]))
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out. You can only iterate once through a mock iterator, after that it is exhausted. To get around this use MagicMock and its iterator, which can be used as many times as you like.

Comment: Any conforming iterator will be exhausted after you iterate through it once. You need to stop reusing the same iterator every time.

Comment: @Vayelin could you provide a working example on how to mock an iterator to be iterated over multiple times? Thats what your question asks for right?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `side_effect` parameter of `Mock` to override the `__next__` attribute of the class you're testing instead.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock):

> If `side_effect` is an iterable then each call to the mock will return
>   the next value from the iterable.

Example:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock

class Iterable:
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

Iterable.__next__ = Mock(side_effect=[1, 2, 3])

for i in Iterable():
    print(i)
```

This outputs:

```
1
2
3
```